# KivyMD: Put/Add a MDDataTable into a RecycleBoxLayout on a screen with MDBottomAppBar

Tags: python, kivymd

I need help  for adding a MDDatatable. I want to add a MDDatatable into the RecycleBoxLayout with `add_widget(datatable)`. But the screen remains empty, the datatable doesn't appear. All other functions in the navigation e. g. fade in / out are working fine.

I have tried many ways without success.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty,StringProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (300, 500)

screen_helper= """

Screen:
   
   NavigationLayout:
       ScreenManager:
           id : scrn_manager
           Screen:
               
               BoxLayout:
                   orientation: 'vertical'
  
                   MDLabel:
                       text: 'Meine Einkaufsliste'
                       
                       size_hint_y: None
                       height: self.texture_size[1]
                       halign: "center"
                   RecycleView:
                       id: rv
                       key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
                       key_size: 'height'

                       RecycleBoxLayout:
                           id: rbl
                           orientation: 'vertical'
                           height: dp(650)
                           width: dp(250)
                           
                   MDBottomAppBar:
                       MDToolbar:
                           title: 'Tools'
                           icon: "git"
                           type: "bottom"
                           md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                           specific_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
                           left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                           #on_action_button: app.navigation_draw()
                           elevation: 10
                           MDIconButton:
                               icon: 'magnify'
                           MDTextField:
                               id: search_field
                               hint_text: 'Search icon'
       MDNavigationDrawer:
           id: nav_drawer             
           BoxLayout:
               orientation: 'vertical'
               spacing: '8dp'
               padding: '8dp'
               
               MDLabel:
                   text: 'Tools'
                   size_hint_y: None
                   height: self.texture_size[1]
               ScrollView:    
                   MDList:
                       OneLineIconListItem:
                           on_release: app.new_item()
                           text: 'Neuer Artikel'
                           IconLeftWidget:
                               icon: 'camera-plus'
                       OneLineIconListItem:
                           on_release: app.item_upload()
                           text: 'Synchro auf Server'
                           IconLeftWidget:
                               icon: 'file-upload'
                           
"""


class ShoppinglistApp(MDApp):
   column_data = ListProperty([])
   row_data = ListProperty([])
   
   def build(self):

       self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)  
       self.data_table()
       
       return self.screen
   
   def data_table(self):
       self.datatable = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5},
                               size_hint=(0.9,0.6), 
                               check=True,
                               rows_num=10,
                               column_data=[("Artikel",dp(30)),
                                            ("Menge",dp(15)),
                                            ("Geschäft",dp(30))
                                            ],
                               row_data=[("Tee: Earl Gray", "1", "Kaufland"),
                                         ("Kartoffeln", "2,5 kg", "Kaufland"),
                                         ("CW Obst&Sahne", "1", "Kaufland"),
                                         ("Bananen etwas grün ", "5", "Aldi"),
                                         ("Mangosaft ", "1", "Kaufland"),
                                         ("Pizateig von Omas Kühltruhe ", "1", "Edeka"),
                                         ("Rinderrouladen Oberschale", "4", "Edeka"),
                                         ("Joghurt 4er ", "2", "Kaufland")
                                         ]
                               )
       self.datatable.bind(on_check_press=self.check_press)
       self.datatable.bind(on_row_press=self.row_press)
       self.screen.ids.rbl.add_widget(self.datatable)
       
       
   
   def navigation_draw(self):
       print("NAV")
   
   def check_press(self, instance_table, current_row):
       print(instance_table, current_row)
       
   def row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
       print(instance_table, instance_row)   
       
   def new_item(self):
       print('Neuer Artikel')
       
   def item_upload(self):
       print('Hochladen')
   
ShoppinglistApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is this line:

```
self.screen.ids.rbl.add_widget(self.datatable)
```

try:

```
self.screen.add_widget(self.datatable)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already tried your suggestion, it makes the list appear but blocks navigation and functions. Sorry, but this suggestion doesn't solve my problem.